# How to get last order id in Magento 2.3?

Tags: orders, magento2.3

I want to get last order's **order id** at any page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch Last order id of order by `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` Object.

You need to create **__construct( )** function for define dependency of Session Class

```
<?php
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
```

*Call method to get last order id using below way,*

```
$orderId = $this->checkoutSession->getData('last_order_id');
```

**$orderId** is your recent order id for a store.